# Gauss lemma in UFDs

Tags: commutative-algebra, galois-theory

Let $A$ be a UFD, and $f\in A$ a square-free element. Define the integral domain $B:=A[z]/(z^2-f)$, and consider a monic polynomial $F(T) \in B[T]$ such that $F(\alpha) = 0$ for some $\alpha \in FF(B)\setminus FF(A)$, i.e. $\alpha = g + hz$, where $g, h \in FF(A)$ and $h\neq 0$.

My question is: it is not hard to compute that the minimal, monic polynomial of $\alpha$ is $Q(T) = T^2-2gT+(g^2-h^2f)$, but how does Gauss lemma imply that the coefficients of $Q(T)$ actually lie in $FF(A)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we can assume that $F(T)$ actually lies in $FF(A)[T]$ by replacing it with $\bar F(T)F(T)$, where the bar denotes the involution $z\mapsto -z$. Because $F(T)$ is assumed to be monic, and because $Q(T)$ is minimal monic polynomial of $\alpha$ we must have (in $FF(A)[T]$) that $F(T) = P(T)Q(T)$. Gauss lemma implies that this factorization also exists in $A[T]$